# UI react capybara button click test

Tags: testing, reactjs, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to get a simple menu bar icon to click. However, the id and class is not available. I've tried with page.execute_script().

HTML code

```
<button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500; transform: translate(0px, 0px); color: white; width: 16.6667%; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: rgb(63, 174, 73);">
  <div>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 48px;">
      <!-- react-text: 57 -->Type<!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Capybara code

```
script = "document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click();"
page.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? How could we help you?

Comment: My goal is to click the button. Example would be `find(#some_id or .someclass).click`. However, those are not available in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the only button with tabindex="0" you can just do

```
find('button[tabindex="0"]').click()
```

If you can come up with a css or xpath expression to select the button (and it's visible on the page) you can click it without using execute_script (you're better off not using execute_script because the events are closer to what a user would generate).  Another option is if the button is the only button contained inside an identifiable element you can scope your find to the identifiable element.

```
find('form#my_form').find('button').click()
```

or if it's the first button in a section

```
find('form#my_form').all('button')[0].click()
```

or if it's just the first button on the page and you're coming from a page with no buttons

```
all('button', minimum: 1)[0].click()
```

Your execute_script didn't work because you're searching by class name but according to your html the button doesn't have any class attribute set. Anyway you're always better off with Capybara not using execute_script if possible, since execute_script has no waiting or retrying behavior associated with it and shortcuts a number of checks which confirm could actually do the action you want tested.